# Unable to click element despite the xpath being accurate

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, webautomation

I am trying to click the first element from a data table on the dashboard, as soon as I login to the system, but somehow the test case is shown passed after login only, and the record on the data table on the dashboard remains unclicked.

Here is my implementation

Xpath on another file HomePage for the records in data table
[image]

```
    public final List<WebElement> listStudentsWhoMetGoals = 
                driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[@id='table-propeller'])[4]//td[@data-title='Top Student']//a"));
```

Code to click the first record in the table

```
public void clickFirstStudent()
    {
        if(listStudentsWhoMetGoals.size() > 0)
        {
            ExplicitWaitFactory.performExplicitWaitForList
                     (WaitStrategy.CLICKABLE, listStudentsWhoMetGoals);
            listStudentsWhoMetGoals.get(0).click();
            return new StudentTabPage();
        }
        else
        {
            DriverManager.getWebDriver().quit();
        }
    }
```

Test case execution

```
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
                    loginPage.clickLoginButton().setUserName("admin").setPassword("xyzabc").clickSubmit().
                    clickFirstStudent();
```

Explicit factory code

```
    public class ExplicitWaitFactory 
    {
        public static WebElement performExplicitWait(WaitStrategy wait, By by)
        {
            WebElement element = null;
            if(wait == WaitStrategy.CLICKABLE)
            {
                element = new WebDriverWait(DriverManager.getWebDriver(), FrameworkConstants.getExplicitwait())
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
            }
            else if(wait == WaitStrategy.VISIBLE)
            {
                element = new WebDriverWait(DriverManager.getWebDriver(), FrameworkConstants.getExplicitwait())
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
            }
            else if(wait == WaitStrategy.PRESENCE)
            {
                element = new WebDriverWait(DriverManager.getWebDriver(), FrameworkConstants.getExplicitwait())
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));
            }
            else if(wait == WaitStrategy.NONE)
            {
                element = DriverManager.getWebDriver().findElement(by);
            }
            return element;
        }
```

The test case passes right after login and doesn't even call the method to click the record, however if I select another element on the dashboard it gets clicked and action happens, but there is something wrong particularly with this case where I am unable to select the first record from the table

And if I select hardcoded first value from the table I am able to click it but that is not my motive, I wish to have all the values in a list and then click the first one.

Comment: I don't see any `waits` applied. Apply `Explicit` wait for the Element you are trying to click. If this doesn't help, you need put some `Thread.sleep(10000)` before trying to click on that tabel Element.

Comment: I did it, in fact I did put a 10 second explicit wait, removed it and showed my code here.

Comment: What about `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: Yes! that seemed to work with Harcoded value of the first record, but not with this list of element thing.

Comment: I've updated the code above.

Comment: Are you sure that `listStudentsWhoMetGoals.size()` is greater than zero.

Comment: 100% 
Again as I said If I select a hardcoded xpath of the first element the click seems to work fine. Let me attach the picture of my xpath and elements detected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237806/discussion-between-pmadhu-and-enthusiasticcoder).

Comment: Try `ExplicitWaitFactory.performExplicitWaitForList(WaitStrategy.CLICKABLE, listStudentsWhoMetGoals.get(0));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your xpath isn't looking reliable but may work.
2. Ideally I would have used Explicit waits for this.

so instead of

```
public final List<WebElement> listStudentsWhoMetGoals = 
driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[@id='table-propeller'])[4]//td[@data-title='Top Student']//a"));
```

try this

```
public final List<WebElement> listStudentsWhoMetGoals = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("(//*[@id='table-propeller'])[4]//td[@data-title='Top Student']//a")));
```

3. `findElement` uses `implicit wait`

> By implicitly waiting, WebDriver polls the DOM for a certain duration
> when trying to find any element. This can be useful when certain
> elements on the webpage are not available immediately and need some
> time to load.

Please include the below line

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

in case you want to rely on `findElement`. But I would argue with you why ? why not explicit waits.

**Warning:**

> Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause
> unpredictable wait times. For example, setting an implicit wait of 10
> seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds could cause a timeout to
> occur after 20 seconds.

Also remember there are **4 ways to click in Java-Selenium bindings**, Also I see you are looking to click on first element.

**Code trial 1 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='table-propeller'])[4]//td[@data-title='Top Student']//a")).click();
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//*[@id='table-propeller'])[4]//td[@data-title='Top Student']//a"))).click();
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='table-propeller'])[4]//td[@data-title='Top Student']//a"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
Thread.sleep(5);
WebElement button  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='table-propeller'])[4]//td[@data-title='Top Student']//a"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(button).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: ```new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy```

This one worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @cruisepandey, Nice solution but I though OP already placed an explicit wait by seeing this linke `ExplicitWaitFactory.performExplicitWaitForList(WaitStrategy.CLICKABLE`

Comment: @NandanA : Thanks but what is `ExplicitWaitFactory`, never heard it before. Is it with Selenium V4 ?

Comment: Even I too never heard. I think that is custom method built by OP @enthusiasticCoder is that right?

Comment: It is a custom class created by me, I am not sure why it didn't work out. I've added it in my code for your reference

Answer (score 1):

Already question has a good answer but I am just correcting your `ExplicitWaitFactory` code.

```
public class ExplicitWaitFactory 
    {
        public static WebElement performExplicitWait(WaitStrategy wait, By by)
        {
            WebElement element = null;
            if(wait == WaitStrategy.CLICKABLE)
            {
                element = new WebDriverWait(DriverManager.getWebDriver(), FrameworkConstants.getExplicitwait())
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
            }
        }
     }
```

The method parameters are `WaitStrategy` and `By` but you are passing `List<WebElement>` like below,

```
 ExplicitWaitFactory.performExplicitWaitForList
                     (WaitStrategy.CLICKABLE, listStudentsWhoMetGoals);
```

Not acceptable for invalid argument type and change below things to make it work,

**Updated check**:

```
 ExplicitWaitFactory.performExplicitWaitForList
                     (WaitStrategy.CLICKABLE, listStudentsWhoMetGoals.get(0));
```

**Updated method**:

```
public class ExplicitWaitFactory 
    {
        public static WebElement performExplicitWait(WaitStrategy wait, WebElement ele)
        {
            WebElement element = null;
            if(wait == WaitStrategy.CLICKABLE)
            {
                element = new WebDriverWait(DriverManager.getWebDriver(), FrameworkConstants.getExplicitwait())
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ele));
            }
        }
     }
```